# my bootstrap button is not coming in the jumbotron

Tags: html, css

Find below my code. The problem is that if i put the button inside the `jumbotron` the carousel goes outside and if i put it after the carousel division the button goes outside the `jumbotron`. i tried using margins but it didn't work.*any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.[This is the image of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSePu.png)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .logospace {
        float: center;
        width: 100%;
        border: 25px LightBlue outset;
        height: 550px;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .knowmore {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        align: center;
        margin-top: 400px;
        margin-right: 400px;
        font-family: American Captain;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="logospace">
      <div class="knowmore">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Know More ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
          </ol>
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active"> <img src="D:\ps\Notepad++\tech360.jpg" alt="A Sam Hawkz Production" style="height:480px"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="D:\ps\Notepad++\para.jpg" alt="Welcome to tech360.com" style="height:480px"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="D:\ps\Notepad++\top2.jpg" alt="A Sam Hawkz Production" style="width:100%;height: 480px;"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="D:\ps\Notepad++\top.jpg" alt="A Sam Hawkz Production" style="width:width:100%;height: 480px;"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="D:\ps\Notepad++\top3.jpg" alt="A Sam Hawkz Production" style="width:100%;height: 480px;"> </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, you want your button to be inside the jumbotron?

Comment: Put your button div inside the <div id="myCarousel"...> and set the margin-top for the .knowmore selector to a negative number, e.g. -50px, instead of 400px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the button in the visual carousel, stick it in the `<div class="item">...</div>` tag. That will put it in the slide though.

If you want it to sit on top but without putting it into every slide, you can do

```
.logospace {
  position: relative;
}
.knowmore {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px; //or wherever you want to place it
  left: 100px; //or wherever you want to place it
}
```

Position absolute pulls it out of the document flow, which allows you to move it around the page without effecting the other items. A word of warning though, it will get its boundaries (ie, the location of top/right/bottom/left: 0;) from the first ancestor that also has a position set. This is why I put `position: relative;` in `.logospace`. Its essentially making a canvas for the button to be on.